# how to pull x number of revisions with Tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

i have a repo which has like 1000 revisions and the source up to this point is 1.5GB.

The thing is I started make the clone on a system, the clone up to 100 revisions. Now when i will pull, it will pull the rest 900 revisions all together.

Please don't ask why the need but is there a way i can pull the next 100 or any number of revisions, then again in another go some more and keep repeating this until I am up to date with the most recent change-set.

b.t.w I am using TortoiseHG 2.7.1

Comment: You've got the right answer down below, but just to mention it -- you should only need to do a full, everything clone once _ever_.  If you want another clone on the same machine, you can clone from local (fast!) and then pull from the original location to update it.  Not always worth doing that when the origin is fast and the repo is slow, but when cloning is a big hassle -- do it locally (or even from a flash drive) and then pull/push back to the origin, which will be incremental, small, and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg pull -r N`, where N - increased number or "last pulled revision" instead of defaut `tip`

```
hg pull -r 200
hg pull -r 300
...
hg pull -r 900
hg pull
```

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseHg GUI you can click "Check for incoming changes" button in the toolbar and select revisions you want to pull.